# Authentication from Development to Release

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, ssl

I have a small web project to develop for a friend that will be incorporated into a small existing website using Visual Studio 2015.

A user has to be logged in, requiring a secure connection. I cannot use the existing website to authenticate with their SSL/Certificate during development because the URL will not be the same (or at least I don't know how).

Social media logins or traditional email/password logins can get involved to implement (new user, existing user, lost passwords, change passwords). I have only done it once before, so I would rather not have to change all of those settings from the development site to the existing site after it all gets working.

How do experienced people do this?

Comment: If anyone has example code, please show it in C#. That tag was removed by others.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it using separate configuration files for each environment.

- Each environment has specific configuration in its own file:
  [image]
- Each config file can have different security-concen configuration:

  - appsettings.Local.json

```
{
  "TokenValidationConfig": {
    "ValidAuthority": "https://localhost:8394",
    "RequireHttpsMetadata": "false"
  },
  "HttpsConfig": {
    "CertificateIdentifier": "Unnecessary for local env"
  }
}
```

- appsettings.Prod.json

```
{
  "TokenValidationConfig": {
    "ValidAuthority": "https://xxx.xxx.com"
  },
  "HttpsConfig": {
    "CertificateIdentifier": "https://xxx.xxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/wildcard-xxx-xxx"
  }
}
```

- Current environment is specified in environment variable, and then is read on startup:

  new WebHostBuilder()
  .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
  {
  var envName = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;

  ```
    config
        .AddJsonFile(
            path: "appsettings.json",
            optional: false,
            reloadOnChange: false)
        .AddJsonFile(
            path: $"appsettings.{envName}.json",
            optional: false,
            reloadOnChange: false);
  ```
- Consider official documentation on the matter:

  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration
  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#json-configuration-provider